# Summarise coverage of variables by selecting non NA values

Tags: r

Suppose I have a dataframe such as the following

```
ID Year Var1 Var2 Var3 Var4
1  2001  1    1     3    NA
2  2001  2    3     8     7
3  2002  NA   4     2     1
4  2003  2    8     NA    8
5  2006  NA   NA    NA    NA
6  2007  2    NA    8     8
7  2007  6    7     7     3
```

I need to identify the coverage of each variable. A variable is covered as long as it has one non-NA observation (so for example, Var4 is covered in 2001 because even though it has one NA, it also has an actual value)

I want to summarize the coverage for all variables and pivot year to be the column names and variables to be the rows, with a 1 for each cell in which a variable-year is covered. The desired output would be the following:

```
Var 2001 2002 2003 2006 2007
Var1 1    0    1    0    1
Var2 1    1    1    0    1
Var3 1    1    0    0    1
Var4 1    1    1    0    1
```

I believe this should be possible with `dplyr` but I have not found the right combination of `pivot_wider` and `summarise` perform this reformatting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
+(xtabs(values~.,cbind(stack(df, -(1:2)), Year = factor(df[,'Year'])))>0)
      Year
ind    2001 2002 2003 2006 2007
  Var1    1    0    1    0    1
  Var2    1    1    1    0    1
  Var3    1    1    0    0    1
  Var4    1    1    1    0    1
```

---

```
df %>%
  pivot_longer(starts_with('Var'))%>%
  pivot_wider(names_from = Year, id_cols = name, values_fn = ~+any(!is.na(.)))

      name   `2001` `2002` `2003` `2006` `2007`
     <chr>   <int>  <int>  <int>  <int>  <int>
    1 Var1       1      0      1      0      1
    2 Var2       1      1      1      0      1
    3 Var3       1      1      0      0      1
    4 Var4       1      1      1      0      1
```

---

```
df %>%
  pivot_longer(starts_with('Var'))%>%
  summarise(value = +any(!is.na(value)), .by = c(Year, name))%>%
  pivot_wider(names_from = Year, id_cols = name)

 name  `2001` `2002` `2003` `2006` `2007`
  <chr>  <int>  <int>  <int>  <int>  <int>
1 Var1       1      0      1      0      1
2 Var2       1      1      1      0      1
3 Var3       1      1      0      0      1
4 Var4       1      1      1      0      1
```

Answer (score 1):

One-liner, base R.

```
cbind(Var=names(df[3:6]), +rbind.data.frame(by(df[3:6], df$Year, \(x) !sapply(x, anyNA))))
#    Var X2001 X2002 X2003 X2006 X2007
# 1 Var1     1     0     1     0     1
# 2 Var2     1     1     1     0     0
# 3 Var3     1     1     0     0     1
# 4 Var4     0     1     1     0     1
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is my tidyverse solution:

```
df |>
  group_by(Year) |>
  summarise(across(Var1:Var4, \(x) +any(!is.na(x)))) |>
  pivot_longer(Var1:Var4, names_to="Var", values_to = "Coverage") |>
  pivot_wider(names_from = Year, values_from = "Coverage")
```

Answer (score 0):

You can first summarize where any are not missing and then transpose the data.frame.

```
library(tidyverse)
   df <- tribble(~ID, ~Year, ~Var1, ~Var2, ~Var3, ~Var4,
                  1,  2001  ,1    ,1     ,3    ,NA,
                  2 , 2001  ,2    ,3     ,8     ,7,
                  3  ,2002  ,NA   ,4     ,2     ,1,
                  4  ,2003  ,2    ,8     ,NA    ,8,
                  5  ,2006  ,NA   ,NA    ,NA    ,NA,
                  6  ,2007  ,2    ,NA    ,8     ,8,
                  7  ,2007  ,6    ,7     ,7     ,3) 


df2 <- df %>% 
    group_by(Year) %>% 
    summarise(across(starts_with("Var"),function(x){any(!is.na(x))})) 


df_t = data.frame(t(df2[, -1]))
colnames(df_t) = df2[, 1, drop = TRUE]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try  the following base R option with `aggregate`

```
d <- aggregate(
    . ~ Year, df[-1],
    Negate(anyNA),
    na.action = na.pass
)
setNames(data.frame(names(d)[-1], +t(d[-1])), c("Var", d$Year))
```

which gives

```
      Var 2001 2002 2003 2006 2007
Var1 Var1    1    0    1    0    1
Var2 Var2    1    1    1    0    0
Var3 Var3    1    1    0    0    1
Var4 Var4    0    1    1    0    1
```